# Return 1 Record from SQL query Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to use a SQL query to create an invoice in VB.  My query returns data in the form:

```
Name      Description      Price
John        Sandwich        4.00
John         Salad          5.00
John         Drink          2.00
```

I'm trying to return only 1 record of the name, but I need all records from the other columns.  Here's what I have so far, but this gives me every record.  Any suggestions?

```
Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

        Dim R As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While R.Read
            Dim xName As String = (R(0).ToString)
            Dim xDescription As String = (R(1).ToString)
            Dim xPrice As String = (R(3).ToString

            MsgBox(xName & xDescription & xPrice)

        End While

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

@Steve

Here's the query.

```
SELECT
               --Invoice Details

'ACCREC' AS Type,
l.Name AS Name,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) AS Date,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(GETDATE() + 7),101) AS DueDate,
'TEST123' AS InvoiceNumber,
NULL AS Tracking,
NULL AS DiscountRate,
NULL AS BrandingTheme,
'Exclusive' AS LineAmountType,
'DRAFT' AS Status,

                 --Item Details

i.Name AS Description,
FORMAT(ABS(
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN dr.RecordType = 0 
            THEN dr.CountOrQuantity 
            ELSE 0 
            END
            ) 
    - 
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN dr.RecordType = 1 
            THEN dr.CountOrQuantity 
            ELSE 0 
            END)), '0.0000') 
        AS Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN 
        (SUM(CASE WHEN dr.RecordType = 0 THEN dr.CountOrQuantity ELSE 0 END)
            - 
        SUM(CASE    WHEN dr.RecordType = 1 THEN dr.CountOrQuantity ELSE 0 END)) <= 0
    THEN 
        FORMAT(i.Price * -1, '0.0000') 
    ELSE 
        FORMAT(i.Price, '0.0000') 
    END AS UnitAmount,
i.CustomID AS ItemCode

FROM 
Locations l JOIN Deliveries d
ON l.id = d.LocationID

JOIN DeliveryRecords dr 
ON d.ID = dr.DeliveryID

JOIN Items i 
ON dr.ItemID = i.ID

WHERE 
d.ID = (
    SELECT TOP(1) 
        dr.DeliveryID 
    FROM 
        Locations l JOIN Deliveries d
        on l.id = d.LocationID

        JOIN DeliveryRecords dr
        on d.ID = dr.DeliveryID
    WHERE 
        l.OrganizationOwnerGroupID = '5555555' AND
        l.Deleted is NULL AND
        ISNUMERIC(l.CustomID) = 1 AND
        dr.Created <= GETDATE()-2 AND 
        dr.Created >= GETDATE()-4 
    ORDER BY 
        d.ScheduledTime ASC)

GROUP BY 
l.Name,
d.ScheduledTime,
i.Name,
i.CustomID,
i.Price
```

Basically, I need the invoice details once, but need every item and item detail.

Comment: So is your desired result one row with all the descriptions and prices stuffed together?  Do you want prices summed?

Comment: You should add more information on your query and on the table/tables involved

Comment: See if this article helps. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Well I'm trying to plug this into an API app to upload somewhere else.  The format I need is: Name, InvoiceNum, Description1, Price1, Description2, Price2, Description3, Price3....

Comment: Even if you are combining all the data in one API call, it may be cleaner and easier to do two separate SQL queries: one for the invoice "header data" and one for all the items. Then you can work with DataTable1.Rows(0) for the header info and iterate over DataTable2.Rows building up Price1, Price2, etc.

Comment: Got it, I'll try to give that a shot